# How to limit the number of records while reading from mysql table using multithreading

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I have 1.5 million records in my mysql table. I'm trying to read all the records in a batch process i.e,planning to read 1000 records in a batch and print those records in console.

For this I'm planning to implement multithreading concept using java. How can I implement this?

Comment: try the `limit` keyword

Comment: this should be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165977/multi-threading-database-reading

Comment: this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651074/how-to-retrieve-mysql-data-using-java-multi-threading

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with multithreading? It is critical to know because you may not need it

Comment: In mysql,instead of rownum and rowid what we can use for splitting the records into chunks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you get all records at once or you get them one by one in a streaming fashion (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448019/3080094)). Alternatively, you can use the `limit` keyword for chunking (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34180941/3080094)).

Whether you use streaming results or chunking, you can use multi-threading to process (or print) data while you read data. This is typically done using a producer-consumer pattern where, in this case, the producer retrieves data from the database, puts it on a queue and the consumer takes the data from the queue and processes it (e.g. print to the console).

There is a bit of administration overhead though: both producer and consumer can freeze or trip over an error and both need to be aware of this so that they do not hang forever (potentially freezing your application). This is where "reasonable" timeouts come in ("reasonable" depends entirely on what is appropriate in your situation).

I have tried to put this in a minimal running example, but it is still a lot of code (see below). There are two commented lines that can be used to test the timeout-case. There is also a `refreshTestData` variable that can be used to re-use inserted records (inserting records can take a long time).

To keep it clean, a lot of keywords like `private/public` are omitted (i.e. these need to be added in non-demo code).

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class FetchRows {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FetchRows.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            new FetchRows().print();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void print() throws Exception {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Properties dbProps = new Properties();
        dbProps.setProperty("user", "test");
        dbProps.setProperty("password", "test");

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", dbProps)) {
            try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
                prepareTestData(st);
            }
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448019/3080094
            try (Statement st = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
                    java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)) {
                st.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
                fetchAndPrintTestData(st);
            }
        }
    }

    boolean refreshTestData = true;
    int maxRecords = 5_555;

    void prepareTestData(Statement st) throws SQLException {

        int recordCount = 0;
        if (refreshTestData) {
            st.execute("drop table if exists fetchrecords");
            st.execute("create table fetchrecords (id mediumint not null auto_increment primary key, created timestamp default current_timestamp)");
            for (int i = 0; i < maxRecords; i++) {
                st.addBatch("insert into fetchrecords () values ()");
                if (i % 500 == 0) {
                    st.executeBatch();
                    log.debug("{} records available.", i);
                }
            }
            st.executeBatch();
            recordCount = maxRecords;
        } else {
            try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select count(*) from fetchrecords")) {
                rs.next();
                recordCount = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        }
        log.info("{} records available for testing.", recordCount);
    }

    int batchSize = 1_000;
    int maxBatchesInMem = 3;
    int printFinishTimeoutS = 5;

    void fetchAndPrintTestData(Statement st) throws SQLException, InterruptedException {

        final BlockingQueue<List<FetchRecordBean>> printQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<List<FetchRecordBean>>(maxBatchesInMem);
        final PrintToConsole printTask = new PrintToConsole(printQueue);
        new Thread(printTask).start();
        try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from fetchrecords")) {
            List<FetchRecordBean> l = new LinkedList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                FetchRecordBean bean = new FetchRecordBean();
                bean.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                bean.setCreated(new java.util.Date(rs.getTimestamp("created").getTime()));
                l.add(bean);
                if (l.size() % batchSize == 0) {
                    /*
                     * The printTask can stop itself when this producer is too slow to put records on the print-queue.
                     * Therefor, also check printTask.isStopping() to break the while-loop.
                     */
                    if (printTask.isStopping()) {
                        throw new TimeoutException("Print task has stopped.");
                    }
                    enqueue(printQueue, l);
                    l = new LinkedList<>();
                }
            }
            if (l.size() > 0) {
                enqueue(printQueue, l);
            }
        } catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Unable to finish printing records to console: {}", e.getMessage());
            printTask.stop();
        } finally {
            log.info("Reading records finished.");
            if (!printTask.isStopping()) {
                try {
                    enqueue(printQueue, Collections.<FetchRecordBean> emptyList());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Unable to signal last record to print.", e);
                    printTask.stop();
                }
            }
            if (!printTask.await(printFinishTimeoutS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                log.error("Print to console task did not finish.");
            }
        }
    }

    int enqueueTimeoutS = 5;
    // To test a slow printer, see also Thread.sleep statement in PrintToConsole.print.
    // int enqueueTimeoutS = 1;

    void enqueue(BlockingQueue<List<FetchRecordBean>> printQueue, List<FetchRecordBean> l) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {

        log.debug("Adding {} records to print-queue.", l.size());
        if (!printQueue.offer(l, enqueueTimeoutS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            throw new TimeoutException("Unable to put print data on queue within " + enqueueTimeoutS + " seconds.");
        }
    }

    int dequeueTimeoutS = 5;

    class PrintToConsole implements Runnable {

        private final BlockingQueue<List<FetchRecordBean>> q;
        private final CountDownLatch finishedLock = new CountDownLatch(1);
        private volatile boolean stop;

        public PrintToConsole(BlockingQueue<List<FetchRecordBean>> q) {
            this.q = q;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                while (!stop) {
                    List<FetchRecordBean> l = q.poll(dequeueTimeoutS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    if (l == null) {
                        log.error("Unable to get print data from queue within {} seconds.", dequeueTimeoutS);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (l.isEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    print(l);
                }
                if (stop) {
                    log.error("Printing to console was stopped.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Unable to print records to console.", e);
            } finally {
                if (!stop) {
                    stop = true;
                    log.info("Printing to console finished.");
                }
                finishedLock.countDown();
            }
        }

        void print(List<FetchRecordBean> l) {

            log.info("Got list with {} records from print-queue.", l.size());
            // To test a slow printer, see also enqueueTimeoutS.
            // try { Thread.sleep(1500L); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }

        public void stop() {
            stop = true;
        }

        public boolean isStopping() {
            return stop;
        }

        public void await() throws InterruptedException {
            finishedLock.await();
        }

        public boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit tunit) throws InterruptedException {
            return finishedLock.await(timeout, tunit);
        }

    }

    class FetchRecordBean {

        private int id;
        private java.util.Date created;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public java.util.Date getCreated() {
            return created;
        }
        public void setCreated(java.util.Date created) {
            this.created = created;
        }

    }
}
```

Dependencies:

- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38
- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.20 (and to get logging shown in console: ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7 with ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.7)